# Will this be a deadlock?

Tags: c++, concurrency

From C++11 book on detector and reactor: Detector detects something then asks reactor to do the job:

```
// Detector:
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex m;
bool flag(false);

// ... detect event

{
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(m);
  flag = true;
}
cv.notify_one();
```

On the other hand, reactor:

```
// Reactor
{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
  cv.wait(lk, [] {return flag;} )
  ... ...
}
```

My question is, if the reactor is triggered first and acquire a lock on the mutex *m*, will it be deadlock, as the reactor will be blocked on cv.wait and the detector can't get the lock for *m*?

Comment: Hard to tell from that narrow code.

Comment: `condition_variable::wait` unlocks held mutex.

Comment: @Xarn could you explain more? condition_variable::wait is suppose to block then how can it unlocks the mutex?

Comment: Mutex has nothing to do with blocking. It releases the mutex then blocks, waiting for a siignal.

Comment: `locking` a mutex is not the same as `blocking` the thread while waiting.

Comment: That the whole purpose of condition variable - it unlocks mutex and goes to wait as atomic operation. This is not the same as waiting on mutex until it is released.

Comment: Please see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait).  As others have pointed out the blocking is with respect to the condition variable itself -- not the mutex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common pattern and use for `std::condition_variable`.

The function [`std::condition_variable::wait`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait):

- Expects a **locked** `unique_lock` to be passed to it.
- Immediately **unlocks** the `unique_lock` before waiting.
- When the function "wakes", the `unique_lock` is **locked again** before exiting.

Hopefully, your book will go on to account for *spurious wakes*.  Edit: ... which is *not a concern* for the predicate form you are using!

Comment: `std::condition_variable::wait()` with predicate is not vulnerable to spurious wakes so OP's code is fine for that

Comment: @Slava ah, thank you.  I did not notice that predicate there.